# How can I represent a form which must be filled in more languages?

Tags: user-interface, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I have a form which must be filled in more languages, so I was wondering: which is the proper way to represent this scenario?

I gave a look at Vuetify components and I found some of them which might fit this role:

- [Chip groups](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/chip-groups)
- [Tabs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/tabs)

[image]
[image]

First one may be the right approach cause Material Design uses it [here](https://material.io/components?platform=web), but I might be wrong (scope is different). Does anyone knows which is the proper one?

Comment: I guess that this is a highly opinionated UX question. Depends on quite a few things and probably needs something iterative overall.

Comment: @kissu do you have any suggestions on how to improve my question?

Comment: Not really, I just think that this kind of question is not suitable for SO and requires AB testing + designer help.